# Can I modify UID of another process?

Tags: android, linux, uid

My native process runs under root on Android device. Is it possible to modify UID of another process in order to give it the root?
The reason is to give an access to some Android "features" that inaccessible for non-root processes.

Comment: P.S. Its important to modify UID for already running process, not starting a new one.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a rooted phone, you can run processes explicitly using (usually) `/system/xbin/su`.  You can't change the uid of a program that's already running, though.  (In theory you could poke at kernel memory and change all the various stored uids, but this is a really bad idea because you can't lock the things you're modifying and if they change or move you could cause a kernel panic.)

Comment: Wrong: I did exactly that: search in memory for the cred structure and modify it. No problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

No. If another app needs root access it needs to gain permissions itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need make a `exec bin(A)` run as root and do:

1. attach to the process which you want to change the uid
2. get the state of the process and save
3. call the setuid system call remote
4. use the saved state to detach the process.

All above can be done by ptrace.
More info can be found here:
http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/6210/print
http://www.phrack.org/issues.html?issue=59&id=12&mode=txt

Comment: If I attach to the process and inject some code to force it to syscall setuid(0), why should it succeed? The target process has dropped root privs earlier. Or I did not get your idea?

Comment: You are right.That will not success. I omit this fact. Sorry for the useless answer...

Comment: it's not useless (+1)  from a privileged process, using ptrace is indeed possible to change uid of any other running process.